# can database engine be included in eclipse plugin?

Tags: database, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse plugin development. I am working to develop a plugin that needs to store large amount of data, as well as search and retrieve from them. I am wondering, if I can use a database for this having plugin dependency. Is there any database engine that comes as Eclipse plugin? I was looking at Apache Derby, but quite unsure about the possibility.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I have been happily using Derby's Eclipse plug-in for data storage and retrieval.  There is a good step-by-step [tutorial](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/index.html) that assumes very little prior knowledge.  Follow these [installation instructions](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html), and you should be up and running fairly soon.

Once you get it installed in Eclipse, there is additional useful information.  Launch Eclipse and bring up the Help for the Derby plug-ins. Help >> Help Contents>> Derby Plug-in User Guide.

Answer (score 0):

For the Eclipse (Rich Client Platform) it does not matter where or how you store data. It is just a framework which helps deliver a rich client interface.

What other functionality will be required by the users of the data? Apart from getting new data in (is client application the right thing fro that anyway). And searching for certain data? If there is a lot of interaction with the data, draw some possible screens, to get an idea about how it should be implemented in eclipse (eclipse plugins).

There are several plug-ins / extensions which can help you getting the data storage functionality implemented.

Comment: Sorry, probably I could not clarify my use case.
My planned plugin is not RCP application. Moreover, the usage (storage, search) of the data is mainly for internal function of the plugin, not necessarily traditional users' data. Rather the users will not see the internal data.